# Deploy a WAR in Websphere ignoring all JEE libraries

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-8

I have an application that uses Java 8 + Spring Boot + Spring 5. I packaged this application in War and I can implement it in Tomcat 8.5+ successfully.

Obviously, when I put the same WAR in WAS, it fails. This inherits the JEE context and the libraries get into conflict.

Can I add some kind of descriptor to ignore the capabilities of JEE in my WAR? I want to use WebSphere like a Tomcat.

Comment: Dont know which version are you using, but you have much better chances with WebSphere Liberty, not traditional one.

Comment: I have to use  WAS 8.5.5.13.

Comment: In general there is no way to disable JEE capabilities in your war. You will have to get rid of all unnecessary Java EE jars, as WAS already has them, not like Tomcat which is just very simple web container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could run my WAR in WAS successfully. I had to downgrade Spring Boot version to 1.5.x because Spring 5 is not complaint with JEE 6.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot did you downgrade from?  Spring Boot 2.x includes reactive Java.  Spring Boot 1.5.x does not.  That might be the reason.

Comment: WAS 8.5.5.x can run JDK 1.8, JDK 1.7 (end of life 201907), and JDK 1.6 (end of life 201804 so already deprectiated). Therefore switch java in this particular WebSphere app server - can be set for each appserver separately.

Comment: I'm using WAS with JDK 1.8 and parent last classloader policy. The result is the same. I have to downgrade to Spring 4.

Comment: It's because WAS 8.5 implements JEE6 instead of JEE7. It is not a problem of the JDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check WebSphere's classloader configuration. Maybe you can make it to load your librares earlier.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/crun_classload.html